# Remove Cesium's Camera Move Event Listener

Tags: event-listener, cesiumjs

I have the following event listener:

```
  viewer.camera.moveStart.addEventListener(function(removeextra) {
     // the camera started to move
     clearoriginal();
    });
viewer.camera.moveEnd.addEventListener(function(addback) {
     // the camera stopped moving

     getresults();

});
```

How can I remove these event listeners? I do not know the syntax.I tried with the following it does not work.

```
viewer.camera.moveStart.removeEventListener(removeextra);
      
viewer.camera.moveEnd.removeEventListener(addback);
```

Comment: What event are you listening for?  The first param for addEventListener is `type` (e.g. click) which is required. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener

On removeEventListener() where is `removeextra` and `addback` defined?

Comment: No, https://cesium.com/docs/cesiumjs-ref-doc/Event.html  
addEventListener(listener, scope) → Event.RemoveCallback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked into Cesium and I think you might rewrite them like this

```
viewer.camera.moveStart.addEventListener(clearoriginal);
viewer.camera.moveEnd.addEventListener(getresults);

// then to remove

viewer.camera.moveStart.removeEventListener(clearoriginal);
viewer.camera.moveEnd.removeEventListener(getresults);
```

Answer (score 1):

viewer.camera.moveEnd.removeEventListener('click',
getresults,// pass the method which you add
false
);

addEventListener() and removeEventListener() are not present in older browsers. You can work around this by inserting the following code at the beginning of your scripts, allowing the use of addEventListener() and removeEventListener() in implementations that do not natively support it. However, this method will not work on Internet Explorer 7 or earlier, since extending the Element. a prototype was not supported until Internet Explorer 8.

Comment: Cesium isn't using the browser's built-in add/remove event listeners for these.  Also Cesium is a WebGL virtual globe that doesn't run in Internet Explorer (except the final few versions of IE 11).